# Using var in map with regex_replace

Tags: ansible

I have a list variable `fqdn_list`.
It's look like:

```json
{
    "ansible_facts": {
        "fqdn_list": [
            "domain.example1.com",
            "    .    .    .    ",
            "domain.exampleN.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to add port number for each element in list.
To do it I tried to use `map` with `regex_replace`:

```yaml
- name: 'Creating url list'
  set_fact:
    url_list: "{{ fqdn_list | map('regex_replace', '$', ':{{ port }}') | list }}"
  vars:
    port: 8089
```

Expected result is:

```json
{
    "ansible_facts": {
        "url_list": [
            "domain.example1.com:8089",
            "      .      .      .   ",
            "domain.exampleN.com:8089"
        ]
    }
}
```

But after execution I see:

```json
{
    "ansible_facts": {
        "url_list": [
            "domain.example1.com:{{ port }}",
            "      .      .      .   ",
            "domain.exampleN.com:{{ port }}"
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I get expected result?
I tried to replace quotes but I get the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your results look like `domain.example1.com:{{ port }}` because your `regex_replace` expression is appending the literal string `{{ port }}`.

Recall that you *never* nest `{{...}}` markers, and you are already inside a `{{...}}` template context. If you want to substitute the value of a variable, the variable name needs to be referenced *outside* of quotes (`"port"` is a string, `port` is a variable reference). The easiest solution is probably using Python-style `%` string formatting:

```yaml
map('regex_replace', '$', ':%s' % port) |
```

That gets you:

```yaml
- name: 'Creating url list'
  set_fact:
    url_list: >-
      {{
        fqdn_list |
        map('regex_replace', '$', ':%s' % port) |
        list
      }}
  vars:
    port: 8089
```

Note that I've reformatted your task using a folding quote operator (`>`) for readability, but syntactically it's identical to your original task except for the changes I've made to the `map` arguments.

---

Running the following example playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    fqdn_list:
      - foo.com
      - bar.com
  tasks:
    - name: 'Creating url list'
      set_fact:
        url_list: >-
          {{
            fqdn_list |
            map('regex_replace', '$', ':%s' % port) |
            list
          }}
      vars:
        port: 8089

    - debug:
        var: url_list
```

Produces this output from the `debug` task:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "url_list": [
        "foo.com:8089",
        "bar.com:8089"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer!
This is a new approach for me and it works fine
I will try to not forget it =)

Answer (score 0):

Given the variables

```yaml
  fqdn_list:
    - domain.example1.com
    - domain.example2.com
    - domain.example3.com
  service: 8089
```

Create the *product* and *join* the items

```yaml
  url_list: "{{ fqdn_list|product([service])|map('join', ':') }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  url_list:
    - domain.example1.com:8089
    - domain.example2.com:8089
    - domain.example3.com:8089
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
  
    fqdn_list:
      - domain.example1.com
      - domain.example2.com
      - domain.example3.com
    service: 8089
    
    url_list: "{{ fqdn_list|product([service])|map('join', ':') }}"
    
  tasks:
  
    - debug:
        var: url_list
```